# Importing JBox2D libraries into a new project

Tags: box2d, jbox2d

I want to import JBox2D libraries into a new project, im new to using exterior libraries so my doubts will seem really stupid but oh well, thats how you learn.

So i kind of followed the tutorial in JBox2D website and i made it this far:

[image]

You can see i have the JBox2D trunk (i didnt quite understood what a trunk is...)
I believe they are all Maven projects, and my goal is to be able to use the engine's libraries in the PhysicTest project you can see opened.

(Probabily stupidly) Im trying to import as you can see in the image and its not working, so i ask your help to solve such a simple problem that is not so simple for me ^^

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import those projects into your project. Go to your project properties, build path, and then click on the libraries tab. There you can add the jbox2d libraries to your PhysicTest project.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for my English. I get the same problem and didn't find the answer. I did the following to get this to work:

1. Download jbox2D from git
2. Import the jbox2D as a maven project to Eclipse
3. After the import is concluded, you can test the project called jbox2d-testbed, right click, run as Java application, choose the TestebedMain
4. Now right click on jbox2D-library project, choose Maven and then Install. This will generate a .jar file located in the target folder
5. Now create a new Java Project and import this .jar file and just use the jbox2D library